# Excel VBA Loop Syntax

Tags: excel, vba, loops, syntax, concatenation

Similar to an earlier question I had, which was easily resolvable with concatenate, I'm trying to do the same for naming a large number of chart series, but not having luck this time.
I commented the line that the macro recorder captured, and have my current (non-working) attempt at concatenation.
Basically I want each series name to be it's number.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+x
'
Dim i As Integer

For i = 92 To 250

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "=" & i & ""

'   ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(92).Name = "=""92"""

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: it seems a cuestion of double quotes. try with   `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "=""" & i & """"`

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = i`?

Comment: Does the `=` need to be part of the name? Looks pretty awkward, are you sure you don't want just `i` to be the name (see above comment)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Dean's suggestion, which did not work.  Luis' actually worked!  but I'm new to stack overflow, so I'm not seeing where I can mark my question answered (maybe I need more time on the system).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "=" & i & ""`

with `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = Trim(i & " ")` and it will just work fine.

Hope it helps